# synchronization sql server SQLite

Tags: sql-server, database, sqlite, synchronization

I'm developing a WPF application that will run on a tablet. The application is developed on top of a Sqlite local database.
I'm facing a problem related to sync between the local sqlite database and a server Microsoft Sql Server 2012 database.

The application sync is structured like an OCA application. I haven't found any library for this kind of task, nor I've found anything about Microsoft Sync Framework. Do you know any tool for this kind of task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at the [Sync Framework Toolkit](https://github.com/Mimetis/SyncWinRT) for WinRT. you should be able to use the same for a WPF app.